# With jQuery Mobile Ajax Navigation how can you tell on server side if page is being loaded by ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, navigation

I would like to return a slightly different page when the page is being loaded by ajax. Can I set jQuery to automatically append a query string parameter that I can use on the server to check if the page is being loaded by ajax? Or would I manually have to add a parameter to my links? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request generated by an ajax call should normally have the following header:

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

jQuery and other well-behaved libraries will usually set this header automatically when making ajax calls.